# How call a controller from javascript after press a button

Tags: javascript, controller, odoo-11

I created a controller that returns a pdf, my problem is that I can't recall it from javascript, by pressing the button with the click action.

I have tried with ajax.rpc and rpc.query but to no avail. If I go to the url I can download the file.

Is there any way to get the file that the controller returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function() {
       window.location = url;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to download a file the simplest solution is to instead a button use a link with the attribute [`download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

```html
<a href="http://yoururl.dev" download>Click here to download</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the url is server's domain.